# Copy and Move Assignment with additional argument

Tags: c++

I have a RAII class which manages a resource.  The problem is, copying the resource requires an additional parameter which is in no way related to the resource, rather is an argument to the resource copy operation.

Thus I have a class copy constructor which requires an additional argument.  This is allowed provided the additional argument has a default value.  I want to write copy assignment and move assignment operators (preferably using the copy-swap idiom), but those do not allow an additional argument.  I could make that troublesome argument a class member, but then users are likely to use it incorrectly, as it would need to be set before every copy or move assignment call.

Any ideas how to approach this?

```
struct Foo{
  void* ptr;
  Foo(size_t){/*allocate*/}
  ~Foo(){/*deallocate*/}
  Foo(const Foo& that, int x = 0 /*required additional parameter for copying*/){CopyMethod(*this,that,x);}
  Foo& operator=(Foo);// cannot implement without int x parameter 
};
```

Comment: Why can't the class mange the extra parameter itself?

Comment: Users of the class all have their own unique parameter; it's not related to the class.  In short, the many users would have to set the member parameter every time before copy or move assignment.

Comment: Can you explain in more details what exactly the value is for?

Comment: This sounds fundamentally suspicious. A real example would be more useful than this toy example so we can maybe recommend a solution you haven't considered.

Comment: The value (parameter) is for specifying which concurrent CUDA API stream_t is being used for the copy operation.

Comment: Better could be to declare the copy constructor as `deleted` and create a dedicated method for copying or better to demand to a dedicated (like a factory) class the copy operation

Comment: @TysonHilmer I can get that for the original object creation, but a copy is supposed to be an exact copy and a move just transfers ownership so I don't see how the parameter would need to be different in order to accomplish that.

Comment: @Marco, yes, I am using this now ``` void Equals(const Foo&, int) const ;// operator= ```  So I have a replacement for copy assignment.

Comment: @Nathan, the problem is that "ownership" in this context relates to which concurrent stream is copying the memory (Foo object).  The objects are passed amongst multiple streams.  In other words, exchanging ownership requires the additional parameter.

Comment: Ultimately this design smells.  Perhaps I should pursue a factory class that adds the stream parameter to achieve copy and move assignment....

Comment: The copy constructor looks suspicious. It will only be used as a copy ctor with its default argument. At that point, why include it in the first place? I'd delete the copy ctor and assignment operator and instead use explicit constructors and ```assign()``` methods

Comment: @Homer512 I agree with your reasoning.  I'm reluctant to delete the copy constructor because that will exclude Foo from most STL containers, even if the copy constructor is never called.

Comment: if something is absolutely required to copy an object then it should be part of the object. " it's not related to the class" yes it is. "users would have to set the member parameter every time before copy or move assignment." thats what is a constructor is good for, a constructor creates an object in a valid state. An object that can be copied wrongly (because one can forget to provide the additional parameter) is not in a valid state

Comment: " I'm reluctant to delete the copy constructor because that will exclude Foo from most STL containers," but if it is called then also STL container will make a "normal" copy without the additional parameter

Comment: @TysonHilmer You can still use the type with STL containers if you provide a move constructor and move assignment operators. Since those don't involve device-side copies, they should not need the cuda stream handle

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number  For it to be a usable class, I agree.  I'm thinking about a wrapper or factory that adds the additional parameter.  The underlying problem is I need to exchange the memory between streams using the additional parameter.

Comment: @Homer512 really good point.  Move operations might be all I need, since copies are a manual task anyways.

Comment: @TysonHilmer -- Please note that one of the most hard-to-find bugs in C++ is one where the copy and/or assignment operators do something other than copying and assigning, or the copy/assignment creates fake copies.  You have two objects that are seemingly copies but are not copies, and then you have a bug somewhere.  That is a nightmare if the program is large enough.  Make default and copy assignment simple, and without side-effects.

Comment: If you want to use STL containers and need copy semantic then can't you (ab)use the allocator? You would pin the container to a specific CUDA stream via the allocator and you add an allocator to your own class that acts as the extra argument for copying.

Comment: Why not create a second class, which holds the CUDA stream id and some smart pointer (unique or shared) to your underlying class? This class would be a proxy or view and your underlying class would be independent of the stream id?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no absolute requirement in C++ that a copy or a move must be done by `operator=` or by a constructor.

All that does is allow a copy or a move to result from a natural use of the `=` operator, or natural object construction.

But there is no universal rule in C++ as to what copy or move must do, or what it means. It means, in practical terms, whatever the class want it to mean. Unsurprisingly, a copy or a move can also be implemented by some random class method, perhaps named `copy_from` or `move_from`.

> I could make that troublesome argument a class member, but then users are likely to use it incorrectly,

Delete the copy/move constructor/operator.

Implement class methods that effect a copy or a move from another instance of this object. Those methods can have hundreds of parameters, if needed. That would be quite cumbersome, of course. In your case just one parameter won't be much of a bother.

So, in the end, a copy or a move gets effected by cheaply default-constructing a new object, and then invoking the appropriate class method, forcing your users to spell out what all the required parameters are, and logically eliminating the possibility of misusing the class's copy/move semantics.

It's also possible not to delete the default constructors or operators, but perhaps implement them in some meaningful way, to effect a copy or a move with the default parameter values, and allowing usage of `=` in most common use cases, but requiring a named class method when things must happen out of the ordinary.

When it comes to C++, the only thing that's etched in stone is its grammar. There is no way to stick some additional values in the vicinity of any natural `=` operator, and have it sucked into a copy or a move constructor. Hence it's not possible to make the default copy/move assignment work this way. But nothing prevents a copy or a move to be implemented by something other than an old-fashioned`=`. Sure, more typing is required to explicitly invoke a named class method, but it is what it is, C++'s grammar is immutable.

Also, keep in mind that the C++ library containers have absolutely no knowledge, whatsoever, about any extra parameters your object requires to be copied or moved. They don't care. Shoving this object in a vector requires, at least, default copy semantics. There is no way to use your object with `std::vector` if it requires some explicit value, of some kind, to be copied or moved. It's a default copy constructor/assignment, or no dice.

Comment: you have convinced me.  Very well stated :)

Answer (score 4):

As a suggestion, it may be useful to store "context" such as the active CUDA stream in a thread-local variable in order to avoid giving it explicitly to each function. Something like this:

```
class WithStream
{
  // cudaStream_t is just an opaque pointer so this is safe
  static thread_local cudaStream_t current;
  cudaStream_t prev;
public:
  constexpr WithStream() noexcept
    : prev()
  {}
  explicit WithStream(cudaStream_t activate) noexcept
    : prev(current)
  { current = activate; }

  ~WithStream()
  { 
    if(prev)
      current = prev;
  }
  static cudaStream_t active() noexcept
  { return current; }
};
```

This allows a usage like this:

```
class Allocation
{
  void* mem;
public:
  Allocation(const Allocation& o)
  : mem(...)
  {
    cudaMemcpyAsync(mem, o.mem, ..., WithStream::active());
  }
};

std::vector<Allocation> copy(const std::vector<Allocation>& o, cudaStream_t stream)
{
    WithStream activate(stream);
    return std::vector<Allocation>(o);
}
```

One may argue that this introduces global state which is a code smell. That is justifiable. However, CUDA already contains this kind of global state: The active device is handled in such a manner. Therefore we don't make things much worse.

Comment: this is a good idea to get around the parameter (stream) requirement.  The problem is I have multiple Operator classes, all with their own stream, within a single-thread context.  Solving the issue as posed requires the Operator instance inform each Foo (memory) instance of it's stream.  There is a more complicated issue of two Operators exchanging a Foo instance, i.e. two-stream exchange.  But that pattern is already solved.

Comment: I took your advice and defined the move constructor and assignment, which allows STL containers.  And Sam's advice and deleted the copy constructor and assignment, in favor of a manual CopyFrom(const Foo&, int) substitute for copying.